# ¿Cómo agregar datos a un tensor en Python?¿

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, matrices, numpy

Estoy haciendo un programa que necesita ir añadiendo pequeñas matrices a una matriz para posteriormente recorrerla en un `for`. Cuando hice algo así en Matlab lo escribia de la siguiente manera:

```
for i=1:5
 matriz_prueba(:,:,i)= *alguna matriz*
```

De esta manera agregaba pequeñas matrices en la matriz que se llama `matriz_prueba`, ¿Existe alguna manera de realizar algo así en Python?

Answer (score 2):

En python sería también utilizando bucles `for`, por ejemplo creamos un tensor 3x5x5:

```
matriz_prueba = []

for d in range(3):
    matriz_prueba.append([])
    for i in range(5):
        matriz_prueba[d].append([])
        for j in range(5):
            matriz_prueba[d][i].append(0)
```

**Salida:**

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Si queremos añadir dimensiones, solo habría que añadir más bucles `for` y si queremos cambiar el tamaño tenemos que cambiar los números que aparecen dentro de `range()`

Otra manera de hacer lo mismo pero más *Pythonico* es usar [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp)

```
matriz_prueba = [[[0 for d in range(5)]  
                   for i in range(5)]
                   for j in range(3)]
```

Con ambas notaciones se consigue lo mismo, esta al comenzar en Python parece más liosa, por lo que puedes usar la primera.

### Usando librerías

Aunque sin dudas para cálculo numérico se suelen usar librerías en Python y la más usada es [Numpy](https://numpy.org/). Se puede instalar mediante [Pypi](https://pypi.org/) ejecutando el siguiente comando en terminal

```
pip install numpy
```

Una vez instalada, la importamos y creamos nuestro tensor de la siguiente forma:

```
import numpy as np

np.zeros((3,5,5))
```

**Salida:**

```
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

Esta última es la forma más común de crear matrices en Python

Answer (score 0):

Definamos una matriz `alguna_matriz` con dimensiones (x,y) y datos de tipo `algun_tipo` (puede ser float, int, ...). Queremos construir una matriz `matriz_prueba` de dimensión (x,y,z) a partir de `alguna_matriz`.

**Si `alguna_matriz` permanece igual en cada iteración** del ciclo `for` en tu código Matlab, se puede evitar el uso de `for` en Python con el siguiente código:

```
import numpy as np

# Alocación de memoria para una matriz de dimension (x,y,z)
matriz_prueba = np.empty((x,y,z), dtype=algun_tipo)

# Llenar matriz_prueba con los valores de alguna_matriz
matriz_prueba[:] = alguna_matriz[:,:,None]
```

(El índice `[:,:,None]` aumenta la dimensión de alguna_matriz. Véase [este enlace](https://qastack.mx/programming/29241056/how-does-numpy-newaxis-work-and-when-to-use-it))

**Si `alguna_matriz` cambia en cada iteración**, no se puede evitar el `for`. Con matrices pequeñas, recomiendo usar "list comprehension" y después transponer la matriz_prueba para reordenar las dimensiones (z,x,y) en (x,y,z):

```
matriz_prueba = np.array([alguna_matriz for i in range(z)]).transpose(1,2,0)
```

(donde alguna_matriz es diferente en cada iteración). También puedes usar "append", pero esto es más lento en general:

```
matriz_prueba = []
for i in range(z):
    matriz_prueba.append(alguna_matriz)
matriz_prueba = np.array(matriz_prueba).transpose(1,2,0)
```

La [respuesta de Rubiales Alberto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/463520) ya explica cómo funcionan "append" y "list comprehension".

"List comprehension" y "append" funcionan bastante bien con matrices pequeñas. Pero con matrices grandes (digamos x,y,z > 500), sería mejor alocar el espacio en la memoria con `np.empty` antes de definir los elementos de matriz_prueba para reducir el tiempo de computación:

```py
# Alocación de memoria para una matriz de dimension (z,x,y)
matriz_prueba = np.empty((z,x,y), dtype=algun_tipo)

# Llenar matriz_prueba con los valores de alguna_matriz
for i in range(z):
    matriz_prueba[i] = alguna_matriz

# Reordenar dimensiones (z,x,y) en (x,y,z)
matriz_prueba = matriz_prueba.transpose(1,2,0)
```

También funciona el siguiente código, que es muy parecido a tu código Matlab, pero es un poco más lento que el código de arriba.

```py
matriz_prueba = np.empty((x,y,z), dtype=algun_tipo, order='F')
for i in range(z):
    matriz_prueba[:,:,i] = alguna_matriz
```

En la alocación de memoria con `np.empty`, añadí el argumento `order='F'` para que numpy ordene la matriz como en Fortran en vez de C (véase [este wiki](https://es.xcv.wiki/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)). En este caso, el orden Fortran es mucho más rápido que el orden C porque el ciclo `for` itera sobre la última dimensión de matriz_prueba.